# How to scale an widget in specified in qt

Tags: qt, layout, widget, scale

I have divided my main screen in 4 areas as border-layout as center,right,left and bottom. The right, left and bottom areas are small and contain only buttons. My center area has to display the different widgets and forms depending on the buttons pressed in right/left/bottom areas.

Can anybody suggest how I can design my forms or widgets so that when I show the widget in the center area, it will fit into the center area and all the items inside this will be scaled rationally.

Please refer to the attached image file for a better idea.

If my explanation is not clear please let me know I will try better.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already have a decent start. If you only have icons, typically icons won't be able to expand much so you will want your left,bottom and right containers to be non-expanding.

The center container (most likely a QStackedWidget in your case) will be expanding both horizontally and vertically.

You will also need to add spacers at the bottom of left area and right area.

The bottom area can also use spacers on both sides.

In short

- Bottom area: sizePolicy: Preferred/Minimum, maximumSize: inf/40
- Left area: sizePolicy: Minimum/Preferred, maximumSize: 40/inf
- Right area: sizePolicy: Minimum/Preferred, maximumSize: 40/inf
- Center area: sizePolicy: Preferred/Preferred, maximumSize: inf/inf

Here is what you can do with drag and drop within QtDesigner
[image: Designer View]

Here is what it looks like
[image: Normal size UI]

Here is what it will look like expanded. Notice that although the main area is bigger, the buttons sides remain the same.
[image: Expanded UI]

Comment: thats a pretty good suggestion. I am going to implement it. But still I would like to ask my question in a different way. As I am designing for a hand-held device the main screen-size will be remaining same all the time and the center area size is also fixed. But If I will put widgets(containing buttons,txtBoxes and levels etc) of different size, will it automatically fit to the center area?

Comment: If the center widget/frame has a layout, yes.